# Exclude native library in Gradle Android build

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Contrary to many other posts on this topic, I want to **exclude** a native library from an Android build with Gradle.

`libfoo.so` resides in a library project in the default directory `thelib/src/main/jniLibs`. In my main project's build.gradle I try to exlude the file as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    all{
        jniLibs {
            exclude '**/libfoo.so'
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work though, the file is still in the final APK. I tried different path specifications already, but none of them work.

Is this even possible, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is an old question, i solved my problem with the following

```
packagingOptions {
 exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libfoo.so'
}
```

Hope it helps someones...

Note:
On further searching someone had already solved a similar issue;
[Gradle exclude arm64 libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441359/gradle-exclude-arm64-libs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply anyway! I later encountered this error: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185982 , but since your solution technically works for the simple case I described, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @langerhans thanks for that... in my case i never encountered the dependency issue but what i did was to add a conditional flag to my build.gradle and do something like this in my dependencies section

         if(flag_is_set) compile 'com.foo:libfoo:1.0.0';

and also in my packagingOptions section;

         if(flag_is_set) exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libfoo.so'

Comment: I have to admit my use case is a bit odd, but the dependency is required regardless as it holds a fallback implementation of the native libs features. Thanks anyway!