# Gradle exclude arm64 libs

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an application including two libraries, where both of them have dependencies on native libraries. Both are included using gradle so the structure looks like this:

MyApp

```
- Libary1
-- x86, armeabi native libs
- Library2
-- Library3
--- x86, armeabi, arm64-v8a
```

I want to remove the arm64 support as i would also need that *.so for Library1, which i don't have. (so currently i get an UnsatisfiedLinkError on arm64 devices)

I already tried this: (with abiFilters "armeabi", "x86")
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30799825/3325222

But i still get the arm64 folder and *.so files in my apk... is there something i'm missing? That abiFilter stuff should even work if the native libs are deeper inside the dependency hierarchy right?

Thanks in advance for any support :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a solution by excluding the specific *.so files that were just added inside the architectures i didn't want to support:

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/lib.so'
  exclude 'lib/mips/lib.so'
}
```

Comment: Hero! Thank you! I excluded all the jnis using exclude 'lib/**' (2 asterisks). See: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30799825/3325222 worked for me in a similar situation. However, that solution is actually deprecated.

There is new SDK support in experimental Gradle 2.5 which supports architecture filters: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips