# Android apk - How to exclude a .so file from a 3rd party dependency using gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have an android project with several dependencies.
Two of them (let's call them dependency A and B) have native libraries (.so files).

Dependency A has the following architectures: arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86 and x86_64.
Dependency B has the following architectures: armeabi, x86

Thus when my app runs on an armeabi-v7a device (for instance), and dependency B calls a native method, it cannot find the relevant library to get it from (as it is not present in armeabi-v7a folder and does not fall back automatically to armeabi where the library is).

Is there any way to work around this? 
For instance, can I add some configuration to my build.gradle file in order for arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, and x86_64 folders not to be integrated to my final apk?

I have tried packagingOptions / exclude, but with no results : the folders in questions are still there.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try a clean build, I didn't and it was still picking up the files from the previous build. I ended up deleting my app/build/ folder just to be sure.

```
android { 
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libSomeLibYouDontWant.so'
    }
}
```

Worked for me on an app that was previously crashing.

An alternative would be to use

```
android{
    defaultConfig{
        ndk{
            abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
        }
    }
}
```

There are some similar questions which might be helpful

[Gradle exclude arm64 libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441359/gradle-exclude-arm64-libs)

[How to use 32-bit native libraries on 64-bit Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782848/how-to-use-32-bit-native-libaries-on-64-bit-android-device)

Comment: Additionally, you can use the following syntax to **ignore an entire ABI folder**, for example, for `armeabi-v7a` folder: `exclude "lib/armeabi-v7a/**"` (See [PackagingOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html))

Comment: this will completely exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libSomeLibYouDontWant.so' from project what if we need to exclude in particular dependency.

Comment: The excluding doesn't work for me for some reason. Only the one with the `abiFilters`. How come?

Answer (score 0):

The modern way (as of AGP ~8.0.0) to exclude jni libs from the final APK is:

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
android {
  packaging {
    jniLibs {
      // Exclude all x86 lib variants
      excludes += "/lib/x86/*.so"

      // Exclude a specific lib of all architectures
      excludes += "/lib/**/libYouDontWant.so"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this is only for jni libs! Any other globs for resources should use `packaging.resources.excludes`:

```
android {
  packaging {
    resources {
      excludes += "/**/*.kotlin_builtins" // (example)
    }
  }
}
```