# Gradle exclude lib imported by dependence from built apk

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using one api in my project that is maintained by a small team of developers and not very good ones.

This api intent to manage payment process with a specific gateway from brazil, so if I dont use this api i would need to reverse engineer all the gateway process what woult be even more complicated.

The api has many flaws and i'm always in contact with the developer team to fix them but there is one major problem in my point that they are not willing to solve

[image]

They do import fresco and add those libs into their dependency BUT IM 100% SURE THEY DONT USE IT

I've checked fresco documentation and the `libwebp.so` is intent to load webp images in older versions of android, my app is minsdk 16 it doesn't need it anyway

the other lib i dont know what is the usage but i'm pretty sure they dont use it, they just included because someone told them to do...

My app have a final apk size around 3MB and after including this only payment api it got 6MB size (unnaceptable in my opinion since a payment gateway should be as small as possible)

THE QUESTION IS:
How can i tell gradle to exclude from the build file those libs imported by the dependency i'm importing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android apk - How to exclude a .so file from a 3rd party dependency using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382057/android-apk-how-to-exclude-a-so-file-from-a-3rd-party-dependency-using-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

```
Example of excluding modules from support library.    
implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }
```

Comment: uhm. have you read the question? besides, this version number does not even exist.

Comment: Martin, I am sorry to mention that this was only for example, not exact solution.

Comment: sorry, but this has absolutely nothing to do with the question. just see the answer I've linked... the topic here aren't support libraries, it's not even Java dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Learned more from your post.