# ND4J Shared library can not be find in Android project

Tags: android, opencv, gradle, dl4j

I'm working on this Android project that need both OpenCV and DL4J. But there is this conflict btw the two during dynamic linking.

In my app/src/main/jniLibs: I have to include `arm64-v8a` folder which has file `libopencv_java3.so`. However, now this causes the linker to try finding `libdl.so` and/or `libjnind4jcpu.so` in this `arm64-v8a` folder, which obviously won't be there since DL4J is added from remote repository.

So, is there a way to explicitly tell Gradle to find `libdl.so` and/or `libjnind4jcpu.so` from the remote repository? Or what would be your way to find to solve this issue?

---

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 25
     buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 6 // start from 1
    versionName "1.3.2" // start from 1.0
    multiDexEnabled true
    jackOptions { // for Java 1.8
        enabled true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions { // for unsigned release build error on Time and Date picker
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}



}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')
    compile 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:2.0.1'
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-3.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/glide-3.7.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/flickrj-android-2.0.0.jar')
    compile 'org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:0.7.2'
    compile 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.7.2'
    compile 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.7.2:android-x86'
    compile 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.7.2:android-arm'
//    implementation 'org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:0.9.1'
//    implementation 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.9.1'
//    implementation 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.9.1:android-x86'
//    implementation 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.9.1:android-arm'
//    implementation 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:openblas:0.2.19-1.3:android-x86'
//    implementation 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:openblas:0.2.19-1.3:android-arm'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10'
    compile project(':mysql-connector-java-5.1.43-bin')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary340')
```

Error:

```
 E/linker: library "/system/lib64/libdl.so" ("/system/lib64/libdl.so") needed or dlopened by "/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace: [name="classloader-namespace", ld_library_paths="", default_library_paths="/data/app/gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener-1/lib/arm64:/data/app/gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a", permitted_paths="/data:/mnt/expand:/data/data/gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener"]
02-01 15:41:09.975 20294-22826/gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
                                                                              Process: gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener, PID: 20294
                                                                              java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder.getInstance(NativeOpsHolder.java:45)
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.ops.NativeOpExecutioner.<init>(NativeOpExecutioner.java:41)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initWithBackend(Nd4j.java:5646)
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initContext(Nd4j.java:5554)
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.<clinit>(Nd4j.java:189)
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.read(Nd4j.java:2328)
                                                                                  at org.deeplearning4j.util.ModelSerializer.restoreMultiLayerNetwork(ModelSerializer.java:216)
                                                                                  at org.deeplearning4j.util.ModelSerializer.restoreMultiLayerNetwork(ModelSerializer.java:167)
                                                                                  at gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener.Cells.<init>(Cells.java:117)
                                                                                  at gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener.CameraActivity.ProcessImage(CameraActivity.java:1104)
                                                                                  at gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener.CameraActivity$8.run(CameraActivity.java:874)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ND4J is probably missing dependencies. For more information, please refer to: http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder.<init>(NativeOpsHolder.java:40)
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder.<clinit>(NativeOpsHolder.java:16)
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder.getInstance(NativeOpsHolder.java:45) 
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.ops.NativeOpExecutioner.<init>(NativeOpExecutioner.java:41) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initWithBackend(Nd4j.java:5646) 
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initContext(Nd4j.java:5554) 
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.<clinit>(Nd4j.java:189) 
                                                                                  at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.read(Nd4j.java:2328) 
                                                                                  at org.deeplearning4j.util.ModelSerializer.restoreMultiLayerNetwork(ModelSerializer.java:216) 
                                                                                  at org.deeplearning4j.util.ModelSerializer.restoreMultiLayerNetwork(ModelSerializer.java:167) 
                                                                                  at gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener.Cells.<init>(Cells.java:117) 
                                                                                  at gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener.CameraActivity.ProcessImage(CameraActivity.java:1104) 
                                                                                  at gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener.CameraActivity$8.run(CameraActivity.java:874) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) 
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/gov.nih.nlm.malaria_screener-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libjnind4jcpu.so"
                                                                                  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
```

Comment: By quick looking at your gradle it seems that you only include android-x86 android-arm versions of that library. So your options here would either to remove arm64 from your apk or to add arm64 version of that library. See [gradle-exclude-arm64-libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441359/gradle-exclude-arm64-libs)

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Problem solved! So, I went to the post you referenced, and used the abiFilter to exclude arm64-v8a folder in my apk.

Comment: Good to hear, i've presented that as an answer. Also note that it is 2018 already and it is about time to add arm64 support to all your apps (i've posted reason in the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only include `android-x86` and `android-arm` using those lines

```
compile 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.7.2:android-x86'
compile 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.7.2:android-arm'
```

you will be missing arm64 libs in your apk. If you unzip it and look into libs folder you will see smth like

```
 libs   
|-->x86   
|    |-->libopencv_java3.so   
|    |-->libdl.so   
|-->armeabi   
|    |-->libopencv_java3.so   
|    |-->libdl.so   
|-->arm64   
     |-->libopencv_java3.so
```

So when you launch your app it would try to look for libdl in arm64 which doesn't have one.

Possible solutions:

1. Add arm64 version of nd4j lib. Also note that this is preferred because [Google remove 32 bit support in 2019](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html)
2. Exclude arm64 from your build using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441359/gradle-exclude-arm64-libs)